# Add label to column chart of Highchart

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am trying to make this chart using Highchart.js. **Now I have to add labels in the format shown in the following picture.** Can anyone help me out please. I am using ASP.net MVC and jquery for this.

[image]

The view is

```
  <div id="hourlyChart"></div>
```

And JS file is

```
Highcharts.chart('hourlyChart', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    credits: false,
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    legend: { enabled: false },
    xAxis: {
        categories: label
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    }],
    legend: {
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            grouping: false,
            shadow: false,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Target',
        color: 'rgba(189, 195, 199, 1)',
        data: target,
        showInLegend: false,
    }, {
        name: 'Achieved',
        color: 'rgb(242, 38, 19)',
        data: achieved,
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        showInLegend: false          
    }
    ]
});
```

From this I am getting this much result

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data-labels and position them by `y` property. Example:

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            ...,
            dataLabels: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                allowOverlap: true,
                enabled: true,
                inside: true
            },
        }
    },
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            color: 'rgba(189, 195, 199, 1)',
            y: -310
        },
        ...
    }, {
        dataLabels: {
            color: 'rgb(242, 38, 19)',
            y: -330
        },
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hvxbpqj5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek for your help. I wanted to point out that sometimes the labels overlap the axis. For example if you change value of last one in Target data from 700 to 780. But I think I should apply MAX to yaxis based on the max value of target. Thanks for your help. I think I can apply my logic with yours. Let me know if you have any better idea. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi @Drashti Patel, I don't have any better idea. You need to somehow reserve space required for labels.